# How do I set up a multiplayer game of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Please bear with me since I don't play Minecraft, and I am asking this question on behalf of my kids.  They play mainly on a tablet, and want to know if they can set up a game with their friend who lives the other side of the village.

Is this possible, and if so, how?  (Please try to explain in a way that I can understand as a non-techie.)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  We generally try to be as helpful as possible here, especially to moms trying to help their children.  Whenever possible, you should try to provide as much information as your are capable so that you can help us to help you.

Comment: In particular, please tell us which version of Minecraft they are using, what tablets, game consoles, PCs, etc.  There is very likely an answer already on this site that we can point you toward if we have the right information.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

Pros: Easy to set-up.
Cons: Every player has to use the same wireless network

The person that has the world that the players want to connect to, is called the 'host'. The host has to do the following steps:

1. Open the Minecraft PE app
2. Tap the 'Settings' button
3. Make sure that 'Multiplayer Game' and 'Broadcast to LAN' is turned on.
4. Press the 'Back' button
5. Press the 'Play' button
6. Open a world

The other players need to do the following:

1. Open the Minecraft PE app
2. Tap the 'Settings' button
3. Make sure that 'Multiplayer Game' is turned on.
4. Open the Minecraft PE app
5. Press the 'Play' button
6. At the top of the list, they will see the username of the host in green, tap on the username of the host.

Advanced:
Pros: Can be played over the internet and has commands (Like /gamemode 1 to change to creative or /give to get a specific item)
Cons: It's harder to set-up, you'll need a PC.

(I'm assuming you have Windows)

1. Press (Windows key) <kbd>❖</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type "CMD" and press enter
3. You'll see a black box with some text in it, it's called the 'Command Line". Type 'ipconfig' (Without the quotes) in it and press <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>
4. Open your browser (leave CMD open)
5. Find "Default gateway" in the list and type the address next to it in the web browser.
6. What you need to do now is different for every router. I recommend you Google it. The port to use is 19132
7. Go to [Pocketmine](http://www.pocketmine.net/) and click download.
8. Run the file it downloads
9. A new Window will appear.
10. Type "op [username]". Replace [username] with the username of your son.
11. Go to this http://icanhazip.com/.
12. Note the IP Address.

On the iPads:

1. Open Minecraft PE
2. Tap "Play"
3. Tap "Friends" at the top
4. Tap the button with 3 rectangles next to "Add Friend"
5. Give it a name in the name bar (Like "Multiplayer world")
6. In the address bar, type that address you noted.
7. Click on add on the right
8. Do this for every iPad and they can all play together

Xbox Live:

Pros: Simple setup, not the same wifi
Cons: Everyone needs an Xbox Live account

Xbox Live accounts are free, so it's not really a problem.

First, everyone has to do this:

1. Open the Minecraft PE app
2. Tap the 'Sign in' button
3. Sign in or Sign up for an XBL account
4. Tap the 'Settings' button
5. Make sure that 'Multiplayer Game' and 'Broadcast to Xbox Live' is turned on.
6. Tap the 'Back' button

Then, the host has to do this

1. Tap the 'Play' button
2. Tap the world that they want to play on

Then, the others have to do this

1. Tap the 'Play' button
2. Tap the 'Friends' button
3. Tap the world that they want to play on

Realms:

Pros: Host doesn't need to be online, simple configuration menu
Cons: Paid Service

1. Open the Minecraft PE app
2. Tap the 'Sign in' button
3. Sign in or Sign up for an XBL account
4. Tap the 'Play' button
5. Tap the 'Realms' button.
6. Tap the 'Create a realm button'
7. Set up some details about the server
8. If this is your first time, you won't be sent to a billing screen.
9. Complete the billing screen
10. In the settings of the realm, add the friends that you want to play with.
11. Tap on the realm to join it, and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Two devices or more must be connected to the same WiFi network. One of the users must host the server, and the other ones will have to connect to it.

Comment: I'm just guessing that you use the Pocket Edition here, seeing as your kids play on a tablet, not a PC/Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the multiplayer server by getting multiplayer pe then one of them makes a password then everyonelse has to know the password to be able to play together.